# Compiler error using std::shared_ptr with std::thread

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to start thread using a `shared_ptr` from class `Test`, and I get this error:

> `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.3/include/g++-v4/functional:559:2: note: no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::shared_ptr<Test>' to 'std::shared_ptr<Test>&'`

Example Code:

```
    std::shared_ptr<Test> test = std::make_shared<Test>();
    std::thread th(&Test::run, test); // Compiler error


    Test* test2 = new Test;
    std::thread th(&Test::run, test2); // okay
```

Note: In windows with VS2013 works fine the first example.

Comment: This looks like a bug in the gcc version you're using.  Does `std::thread th(std::bind(&Test::run, test))` work any better (it might not, since they might use some common internal code).

Comment: [How odd](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d6618c69f8e3134b)...

Comment: [Doesn't work on GCC 4.7](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c9f655a5bb60e5f) but does work on [4.8](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6817fbaf01485515).

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56505

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the gcc version you're using, as it should work.  And looking at http://ideone.com/GOQ35M it does work

As a workaround, you can try

```
std::shared_ptr<Test> test = std::make_shared<Test>();
std::thread th(std::bind(&Test::run, test))
```